# How to set the subscription for total application

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am doing one application.In that i set the price as $5.And i need to set the monthly subscription for that total application.Means whenever application is installed i want to get the transaction receipt and $5 credit to my account.And after one month again $5 credit to my account.And how to handle the "Manage In-App purchase" in itunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to add your own payment integration and let your to choose auto renewal option